# casting exception when I converting a decimal to a string in a ODBCdatareader

Tags: c#, casting

I am getting a casting exception when I converting a decimal to a string in a ODBCdatareader.

```
  string balanceTotal = "SELECT SUM(BalanceRemaining)  FROM Invoice WHERE  (CustomerRefFullName = '" + comboBox1.DisplayMember + "')";
            OdbcDataReader myReader;
            sqlConnect conect = new sqlConnect();
            conect.sqlReader(balanceTotal);
            myReader = conect.sqlReader(balanceTotal).ExecuteReader(); 
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    String name = myReader.GetDecimal(0).ToString();
                    textBox1.Text = name;
                }
```

Cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

`BalanceRemaining` may not be a `Decimal`.

Use `myReader.GetValue(0)` first, then inspect the type of object it gives you. Then you will know it's safe to cast as that type.